# Pickit 3 Connection Failed

Tags: pic, microchip, mplab

I have been unable to connect to my Pickit 3 through MPLab IPE.
As background, I was never able to download or debug from MPLab X, usually I build the project on MPLab X and download it through the IPE.

Right now the only error showing up is "Connection Failed"

The Pickit3 Serial Number is being detected though, both on the IDE and the IPE.

Things I have already tried:

- Connect Pickit 3 through an external powered USB Hub (3.0 and 2.0), this worked for about 2 weeks, then it suddenly failed again
- Run as Administrator
- Uninstall everything:
  IDE, IPE, USB drivers (from device manager), even compilers (just in case)
- Run on Safe Mode

I have tried on another PC, the Pickit seems fine as it is recognized and can download programs to a MCU

My PC's specs:

- Acer Veriton M4630G
- Windows 7 Professional 64-bit SP 1
- Intel i7-4770
- 8GB RAM

Using PIC32MX460F512L

Any help would be really appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Did you try the following:

1. Does the PIC have power?
2. Did you follow the getting started chapter for connecting the PIC properly? Including decoupling capacitors etc? Is the powerline into the pic clean?
3. Did you try choosing a different programmer, then apply, then pick the PICKIT3? This sometimes resolves the issue.
4. Is the MCLR, PGD and PGC lines used for other stuff? Did you try disconnecting them from other hardware?

Usually if you disconnect the PICKIT3 when MPLABX is running looses the connection until you restart the software.
Sometimes a reboot is necessary, then insert the PICKIT3 and run the software in that order.

Try adding a new administrator user in Windows and login with that. If that works, it's probably a registry issue. You could try copying the new user registry for mplab to the old user (after making backups of course).

Comment: Hello imqqmi
1) Yes, the PIC has power (externally powered)
2) Yes, decoupling capacitors are included in the PCB
3) I have another Pickit 3, which also doesn't work
4) No, all of these lines are used exclusively for communication with the programmer.

I installed a virtual machine (Windows 7) which doesn't have any trouble communicating with the Pickit. 
I can download programs from there but this is far from an ideal case
Thanks for your help!